# Using a subprocess to invoke one py script from another

Tags: python

What is the difference between:

```
Script1.py
#Some python scode
```

#Call Scipt1 :

```
Script2.py
    import Script1
```

vs

```
Script2.py
from subprocess import call
 call(["python", "Script1.py"])
```

Comment: If script1.py contains an `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, then code in that block will be executed in the second example, but not in the first.

Comment: For one thing, `import` pulls that code into the *current* python interpreter, but `subprocess` runs the script in a *new* python interpreter - an entirely different process at the OS level, so there is no chance for shared state.

Answer (score 0):

i think one difference is one interpreter vs two interpreters. subprocess is execute script1.py in another process.

> The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

> Python code in one module gains access to the code in another module by the process of importing it.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-import-system